# slider autoplay mouseout jquery no arranca?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

soy novata y estoy siguiendo un tutorial para hacer un slider (carousel). El tema es que quise

agregarle una pausa cuando el mouse pase por encima del slider por lo cual se me ocurrió hacer un

`<div>` y un `.mouseover` de la misma medida del carousel para que se detenga **y funcionó!** (por ahí es

una idea muy de nuevos pero de otra forma no se me hubiera ocurrido).

## RUTA DEL SLIDER =

1. Abrir la página y que el autoplay/ setInterval del slider se ejecute automáticamente.
2. `mouseover` y que se detenga (esto lo logré)
3. `mouseout` y que el slider siga su curso (setInterval original) (esto lo logré pero de una manera en la que no se ejecuta el paso uno.)

## El problema

que tengo es que no encuentro manera de incorporar el `.MOUSEOUT` y que el slider siga su curso normalmente (`setInterval`), la única forma que encontré es hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var counter = 1;
var caja = document.querySelector("#caja");
caja.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    
    var tiempo = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked = true;
        counter++;
                if(counter > 3){
                    counter = 1;
                }
                caja.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
                    clearInterval(tiempo);
                });
               
    }, 5000);
});
```

Con ese código queda casi exacto como quiero, funciona bien...
Y la consola no me tira error rojo de esta manera.
El problema con el  código de ahí arriba es que al abrir la página el `setInterval` no se ejecuta automáticamente, supongo porque el `.MOUSEOUT` se antepone, por lo cual tengo que poner y sacar el cursor para que se inicie y la idea es que se ejecute automáticamente al abrir la página...

Otra idea que tuve es, después del `.mouseover`, poner el `.MOUSEOUT` y agregar un `return tiempo` pero no funciona.

## ¿Alguna pista, idea, indicio que me puedan dar?

Les dejo el código entero del slider

```js
var counter = 1;
var caja = document.querySelector("#caja");
caja.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {

  var tiempo = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked = true;
    counter++;
    if (counter > 3) {
      counter = 1;
    }
    caja.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
      clearInterval(tiempo);
    });

  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #23E3C9;
}

.slider {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 500%;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
}

.slides input {
  display: none;
}

.slide {
  width: 20%;
  transition: 2s;
}

#caja {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: transparent;
}

.slide img {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 500px;
}


/* css for manual slide navigation*/

.navigation-manual {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.manual-btn {
  border: 2px solid #40D3DC;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
}

.manual-btn:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: #40D3DC;
}

#radio1:checked~.first {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#radio2:checked~.first {
  margin-left: -20%;
}

#radio3:checked~.first {
  margin-left: -40%;
}


/* css for automatic navigation */

.navigation-auto {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 460px;
}

.navigation-auto div {
  border: 2px solid #40D3DC;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.navigation-auto div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

#radio1:checked~.navigation-auto .auto-btn1 {
  background: #40D3DC;
}

#radio2:checked~.navigation-auto .auto-btn2 {
  background: #40D3DC;
}

#radio3:checked~.navigation-auto .auto-btn3 {
  background: #40D3DC;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Image Slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--image slider start-->
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <!--radio buttons start-->
      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
      <!--radio buttons end-->
      <!--slide images start-->
      <div class="slide first">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide ">
        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide ">
        <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <!--slide images end-->
      <!--automatic navigation start-->
      <div class="navigation-auto">
        <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
        <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
        <div class="auto-btn3"></div>

      </div>


      <!--automatic navigation end-->
    </div>
    <!--manual navigation start-->
    <div class="navigation-manual">
      <label for="radio1" class="manual-btn"></label>
      <label for="radio2" class="manual-btn"></label>
      <label for="radio3" class="manual-btn"></label>

    </div>
    <!--manual navigation end-->

  </div>


  <div id="caja">
    hola
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Gracias por la atención y paciencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas crear una función aparte para ejecutar el slider y, al cargar la página, crear el intervalo, llamando a la función. Para esto, es necesario que la variable `tiempo` esté definida en contexto global.

Solo por precaución, evita la posibilidad de que se creen varios intervalos, cancelando el existente antes de volver a iniciarlo.

```js
let counter = 1;
let caja = document.querySelector("#caja");
// Debes definir la variable tiempo en contexto global
let tiempo;
// Crea una función para ejecutar el slider
const sliderMove = () => {
    document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked = true;
    counter++;
    if (counter > 3) {
        counter = 1;
    }
};
caja.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    // Evita que se creen varios intervalos
    clearInterval(tiempo);
    // Vuelve a crear el intervalo
    tiempo = setInterval(sliderMove, 5000);
});
// Asigna el evento fuera del intervalo
caja.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    clearInterval(tiempo);
});

// Al cargar la página crea el intervalo
tiempo = setInterval(sliderMove, 5000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #23E3C9;
}

.slider {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 500%; /* ¿Por qué esta medida, no tiene sentido? */
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
}

.slides input {
  display: none;
}

.slide {
  width: 20%;
  transition: 2s;
}

#caja {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: transparent;
}

.slide img {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 500px;
}


/* css for manual slide navigation*/

.navigation-manual {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.manual-btn {
  border: 2px solid #40D3DC;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
}

.manual-btn:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: #40D3DC;
}

#radio1:checked~.first {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#radio2:checked~.first {
  margin-left: -20%;
}

#radio3:checked~.first {
  margin-left: -40%;
}


/* css for automatic navigation */

.navigation-auto {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 460px;
}

.navigation-auto div {
  border: 2px solid #40D3DC;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.navigation-auto div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

#radio1:checked~.navigation-auto .auto-btn1 {
  background: #40D3DC;
}

#radio2:checked~.navigation-auto .auto-btn2 {
  background: #40D3DC;
}

#radio3:checked~.navigation-auto .auto-btn3 {
  background: #40D3DC;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Image Slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--image slider start-->
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <!--radio buttons start-->
      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
      <!--radio buttons end-->
      <!--slide images start-->
      <div class="slide first">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide ">
        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide ">
        <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <!--slide images end-->
      <!--automatic navigation start-->
      <div class="navigation-auto">
        <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
        <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
        <div class="auto-btn3"></div>

      </div>


      <!--automatic navigation end-->
    </div>
    <!--manual navigation start-->
    <div class="navigation-manual">
      <label for="radio1" class="manual-btn"></label>
      <label for="radio2" class="manual-btn"></label>
      <label for="radio3" class="manual-btn"></label>

    </div>
    <!--manual navigation end-->

  </div>


  <div id="caja">
    hola
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, voy entendiendo. Ahí van unos puntos para semejante ayuda. Gracias.